Drag and Drop - using jQuery to select draggables and droppable -but can't drop since its a ReactApp - DndKit
I have a reactapp that uses the DNDkit library for drag an ddrop. I had a requirement to actually change the behavior of the keyboard drastically. This was for a drag and drop implementation. For some reason I wasnt able to manipulate the behavior of the space and enter keys no matter what I tried - so instead I've gone a controversial route and used jQuery to modify the DOM and capture key events. The problem is - while I can capture key events I need to invoke the drag and drop events which don't see to be working.
The keyboard key map I needed to set are:
Tab - cycle through draggables(theres a set of draggables)
Space - Select a draggable
Tab - Once a draggable is selected - now cycle through droppables
Space - Once on a droppable - drop the selected draggable on the droppable

The part where the draggable gets dropped on the droppable is where I am stuck. Assume I have an id of a draggable and a droppable - how would I use dndkit to in code drag and drop the draggable on the droppable.
